how can you change the background of an outer div after an observed event happens in the inner div?
i was thankfully helped in another post about changing the background of a div based on what month is called but i want it to change the container div rather than the calendar div itsself.
i tried modifying the code to observe the calendardivnode for the change but then alter the bgcontainerdivnode but its not working.
can anyone please help?  this is using the semantic calendar from Adam Shaw


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();

  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");


  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    let monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
    let month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
    changeBackground(month);
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);

  // Function to change background
  function changeBackground(month) {
    const colors = {
      January: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white')",
      February: "url('assets/images/pgs/month2.png')",
      March: "url('assets/images/pgs/month3.png')",
      April: "url('assets/images/pgs/month4.png')",
      May: "url('assets/images/pgs/month5.png')",
      June: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      July: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      August: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      September: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      October: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      November: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      December: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/red/green')"
    };

    calendarDivNode.style.backgroundImage = colors[month];
    calendarDivNode.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    calendarDivNode.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    calendarDivNode.style.backgroundPosition = "right";

  }
  changeBackground(Object.keys(new Date().getMonth()));
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<!-- div bg container for calendar -->

<div class="bgcontainer">


  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <!-- end of div bg container for calendar -->


</div>



the div called bgcontainer needs changed rather than the calendar div but it listens and observes changes in the calendar div.

Your code works. I made a working snippet for you. Why did you not take the code already given and enhance it? I added images from placeholder and added render before the code with the mutation

I also added the init: changeBackground(Object.keys(new Date().getMonth()));

i messed around with that code and just kept breaking it thats why i had to ask for more help. its been so long since i coded but even worse is i never coded with mixed languages like this, only calling functions

I believe I fixed your code above,

Feel free to delete this. It is answered here too

not really, i tried your code and it works for changing the bakground of the calendar but not the div above it. altering your code isnt working atm so i'll wait and ee if anyone else can help

I changed the code to use the backgroundDiv and it works the same

All you really need to do to make this work is just change the <div> you are setting the style tags on.
Also your initial call to changeBackground wasn't getting a valid value passed in - date.getMonth() returns an integer, so calling Object.keys on it didn't make much sense. I've fixed it so it gets the long month name of the current date.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();

  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");
  //select the div which the style changes will be applied to
  const calendarBackgroundNode = document.getElementById("background");


  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    let monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
    let month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
    changeBackground(month);
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);

  // Function to change background
  function changeBackground(month) {
    const colors = {
      January: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white')",
      February: "url('assets/images/pgs/month2.png')",
      March: "url('assets/images/pgs/month3.png')",
      April: "url('assets/images/pgs/month4.png')",
      May: "url('assets/images/pgs/month5.png')",
      June: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      July: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      August: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      September: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      October: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      November: "url('assets/images/pgs/months01.png')",
      December: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/red/green')"
    };

    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage = colors[month];
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundPosition = "right";

  }
  changeBackground(new Date().toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<!-- div bg container for calendar -->

<div id="background" class="bgcontainer">


  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <!-- end of div bg container for calendar -->


</div>




this is great but where did my buttons go?  the different views are gone now

@MachaNeko Which buttons specifically are you thinking of? Do you mean the ones you can add to the fullCalendar header? You can set those as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar if you wish to. For my example I only copied the code you originally provided in the question, which did not include any buttons to begin with.

weird, my code must be having issues then because it had buttons before adding your code but now it doesnt.  i'll check out your link and see whats wrong on my end.  thank you!

@MachaNeko The code you posted didn't have anything which would generate buttons. Maybe you posted an old version in your question, or maybe you added buttons since you posted this, but have then overwritten them by pasting in this answer. Always take care to only paste the bits of code which are directly relevant to the problem you're dealing with. And/or ensure you use source control and commit changes frequently, so you could go back and see if you overwrote any button-related changes, and then easily restore them. Or as I said, it's trivial to add buttons to the calendar, as per the docs.

i posted whatever the code was i had and didnt change it since until i added your code so it's weird the buttons went away. i know you didnt remove them, i guess the calendar is just picky? either way, i'll just readd them. i liked the different view types it had

@MachaNeko i guess the calendar is just picky...no, it just displays whatever buttons you tell it to. If you don't specify anything, you get the defaults. I think you'll find you accidentally overwrote something at some point, but it doesn't sound like you have any source control history to be able to go and check - that's something invaluable which you should seriously think about introducing in your programming work.

i checked my code again, i had it correct already with the tabs i wanted, your code overwrote that by initializing the view.  i got it working again though so all good!
